# Bitmaps appearing with a blue tint when added to a canvas (android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas, android-bitmap

I have been trying to add bitmaps to a canvas, but have so far found that every image i add has a blue tint. I am not using a paint when adding the images to the canvas. My code is below and I have attached the screen shots along with the original images.

Thank you all for the help!

```
while(isItOk) {
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                continue;
            }
            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawBitmap(cuttingBoard,0,0,null);
            c.drawText("0",(float)c.getWidth()/2-50,(float)120, textPaint);
            c.drawText("0/10",(float)30,(float)120, textPaint);
            time = Math.round((frame/FPS) *10)/10.0;
            frame++;
            c.drawText(time +"s",(float)c.getWidth() - 410,(float)120, textPaint);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            try{Thread.sleep(1000/FPS);}catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Blue tinted image, the one that appears on my android device:

[image: Img1]

Original Image:

[image: Img2]

Comment: Hi, your second image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU2ti.png is a white, blank image. Is it supposed to be that way?

Comment: @KeithOYS no, it is not. I think I fixed it, thank you.

Comment: Great, I just edited your question to display out your new image.

Comment: So I think i have narrowed down the problem, the SurfaceHolder format is set to RGBA_8888 and the bitmaps are set to the ARGB_8888 format. Oddly enough there is no way to set the bitmap to RGBA and there is no way to set the SurfaceHolder to ARGB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread may look like I am just talking to myself but I thought I would post my findings in case someone else ran into this problem. The problem was the format of the SurfaceHolder. It could only be set to 32 bit RGBA. Bitmaps can only be configured with the Alpha Pipeline (I think that is the right term?) in the front whereas PNG's contain the alpha pipeline in the back. So I just saved all of my bitmaps as PNG's and it fixed my problem!